# Can I dispute a credit card charge for a hacked Vanilla Visa Gift Card?

Tags: credit-card, scams, gift-card

I bought 4 $500 Vanilla Visa Gift Cards from CVS Store #2149 in Alexandria, VA right before Christmas. I used my Citibank MasterCard to pay for the gift cards.  They were for my employees as a holiday gift. The cards were located near the rear of the store in a remote and unsupervised location. By the time my employees tried to use the card, all of the funds had been drained of a total of $2,000. The funds were used at Apple Stores, Best Buy, etc. I contacted Vanilla..... it was a very frustrating process. I was on the phone to a call center in India for over an hour and a half. At the end of the call, they said I should hear back "WITHIN THREE MONTHS"!!!! They were very non-committal and just described it as a potential "unauthorized use" of the card.

I contacted CVS and they had absolutely no interest in addressing the issue.... just referred me to Vanilla. I feel that CVS has primary responsibility because they sold me a product that had obviously been compromised. With all of the lawsuits and complaints over this issue, they certainly knew that placing the cards in an unsupervised location at the back of the store was inviting criminal activity.

Can I successfully dispute the CVS charge on my personal credit card that I used to purchase these 4 gift cards?

Comment: What is not clear here - but is potentially extremely relevant - is *when* the fraudulent ("drained") transactions took place. Did they take place before or after the time of your purchase from CVS? Also relevant - and varies by store/type of card: Did you get anything other than a standard receipt? For example, does CVS provide an activation code/$ value on the receipt?

Comment: (IANAL) I'll second @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact's question about when the draining occurred relative to the purchase date. If BEFORE then you seem to have a clear VISA claim . ||  If afterwards then it's more complex, as the scammers have the card credentials for an after purchase use. || You were STILL sold a valueless item in the latter case, so have a VISA claim BUT it is harder to prove. || I'd be interested in knowing the answer re timings - it would be useful to be in your question.

Comment: [This](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/29742/gift-card-fraud-to-whom-to-report-how-to-recover-funds-is-the-party-which-iss?rq=1) Q&A is relevant and may or may not be useful.

Comment: Do you have customer protection agencies in your jurisdiction?

Comment: If it says VISA on it how is that not the one and only go to? (after you jump through all the hoops : "where the cardholder has lawfully cancelled his agreement in accordance with the merchant's cancellation policy with an online, phone or mail-order merchant; or the item received is different from what was ordered and documentation exists to support the claim") https://www.visa.ca/en_CA/pay-with-visa/security.html

Comment: @Mazura neither of these options happened here. The purchase was in a physical retail store, so the first condition doesn't work. The item was exactly what was ordered since the OP picked it up from the shelf themselves, so the second condition doesn't hold either. These conditions are for online purchases, which is not the case here.

Comment: The item was different from what was ordered. What was ordered was a card whose number was not known to thieves and what was delivered was not that due to the merchant's failure to secure the product prior to delivery.

Comment: Lots of "good advice" from many :-). || One last try - VISA may be interested in some or all of the suggestions/comments: || The suggestion that they are too keen to make a profit without due diligence, and that || They are willing parties (by default) to theft of their product's credentials and so the cards' contents. || Their security measures are manifestly inadequate. They visibly do not care that their products are being used to enable fraudulent behaviour and that || THEIR CUSTOMERS  are being disadvantaged and || THEIR NAME is being sullied.

Comment: The big take here is don't ever ever give someone a gift card at $500.    $50 is ok... $100 gets into scam territory.    No way $500.    Give them a check.

Answer (score 24):

There were news stories regarding this type of theft in the Washington DC area, as well as other parts of the country.

Yes, complain to the place you bought the card. Yes, complain to police. Yes, complain to your credit card company. Yes, complain to the vanilla card company.

Not complaining masks the size of the scam.

Comment: Definitely complain. Don't expect to get anything back though, other than from the gift card issuer based on unauthorized charge claim.

Comment: And keep a copy of the police complaint. Keep a copy of every document and paper trail. It might be for nothing, but if you ever get to court, being without these will hurt you badly.

Answer (score 20):

Reading the comments it is clear that some people misunderstand the question.

> Can I *successfully* dispute the CVS charge on my personal credit card that I used to purchase these 4 gift cards?

The OP used a credit card to buy a bunch of gift cards which they now claim were drained. The OP is asking whether they can dispute *the purchase of the gift cards*, they already disputed the transactions that drained them.

The answer is - of course you can, but you won't succeed. In order for a merchant chargeback to succeed, the buyer must show that:

- either the transaction was unauthorized - that's not the case here, they did in fact purchase the gift cards,
- or they didn't get what they paid for - that's not the case here, the OP did in fact get the gift cards, the unauthorized charges appeared on the gift cards after the purchase.

Everything else is futile arguments. Yes, the OP has been scammed. No, noone will return the money to the OP unless they absolutely have to. Yes, the gift card company can probably identify this pattern of fraud. No, it doesn't mean that the OP should immediately be reimbursed, they still need to show that they are not in fact the scammer themselves.

---

It is unlikely that you can successfully dispute the purchase of the debit cards, since that purchase was authorized and not fraudulent. Unless you can prove CVS to be negligent, it is unlikely that you can prevail on any claims against CVS either.

I suggest discussing this with a licensed attorney in your jurisdiction for a proper evaluation of your legal chances against any of the parties involved. I also suggest filing a police report for the fraud that occurred.

What you're describing is a pretty common theft scheme called "[gift card drain](https://www.wral.com/story/beware-of-gift-card-draining-scam-here-s-how-to-protect-yourself-this-holiday-season/21205086/)": the scammers take unsold gift cards, scan them and then reseal them again in their original packaging and put them back on the store shelves. Once the cards are sold and activated the scammers have all the information they need to clear them out. There have been [numerous](https://www.foxbusiness.com/lifestyle/gift-card-draining-scam-what-it-is-and-how-to-protect-yourself) [news](https://abc7news.com/gift-card-scam-pinole-police-department-checking-cards-holiday-shopping/14151594/) [reports](https://www.usatoday.com/story/money/2023/12/12/gift-card-scams-warning-2023/71891789007/) on this.

---

There are several people downvoting this answer because it is based on the assumption that the OP may be lying.

So just to make sure we're on the same page: everyone but the OP wil assume that the OP is lying and the OP is in fact the one trying to scam the system.

In order to prove otherwise, the right avenue is an unauthorized charge claim against the gift card issuer, which then will be investigated by the issuer and determined to be true or false. Everyone else will deny any claim because the OP cannot prove they did anything wrong.

For people keep claiming it's trivial to determine the OP is not lying - how exactly is that trivial? The scammers are not doing anything different from legitimate users, and there's no way to distinguish a legitimate transaction from an illegitimate one without knowing anything about the user (which in case of gift cards - the issuers know nothing of). So unless a claim is made and investigated - the issuers have no way of distinguishing those.

For people claiming the OP didn't get the goods - the OP themselves admits that they did. The card was in fact activated with $500 value, the draining occurred *after* activation (which is the delivery event). Any claim that the card was activated with $0 value is easily refutable, and a chargeback on that claim will not succeed.

As to tampered packaging - that's a valid claim only until the cash register.

While letting CVS know that they have a tampering problem is a good idea, it's not going to bring money back to the OP. They will not file an insurance claim unless they absolutely have to. For that - a police report would need to be made, for starters. Maybe a threat of a lawsuit.

Comment: Usually the code to scan would be protected by something you have to scratch away that can't easily be re-added... are giftcard in the US not like this? Do they just have a code "in the open"?

Comment: for gift debit cards, the CVC is printed on the back of the card and is usually not covered. Often times there are gift cards with codes covered, but its easy to remove that layer and replace it again. And even if the scammers don't cover them back, it doesn't even matter because by the time the purchaser unpacks the card and sees the code scratched away, the scammer already siphoned the money away.

Comment: Can you argue that the "goods" purchased were defective? I don't know what grounds you can dispute debit card transactions on in the US.

Comment: The police is the way to go, especially if they get multiple reports of this from the area, or even that store.  There were a couple of arrests last month (one Cali, one Boston) of people caught doing this.

Comment: The OP intended to purchase gift cards with a value of $500, CVS delivered gift cards with a value of $0. CVS did not deliver the goods bargained for therefore, certainly herein the UK, I would expect a chargeback to be successful.

Comment: There's a couple methods by which the gift card drain scam works, and all of them require either CVS or Vanilla to have been exceedingly negligent; thus the product is defective and the chargeback should succeed.

Comment: @Joshua this is not a new scam, and no - the chargeback is very unlikely to succeed. This is an in-person transaction, and the fact that the gift card has not been used by the purchaser has not been established, it's just an allegation. Not sure what you're basing your claim on, I'd appreciate references and citations.

Comment: @deep64blue "CVS delivered gift cards with a value of $0" - that's not true, CVS did in fact deliver gift cards with a value of $500, and that's admitted by the OP themselves. The cards were drained *after* activation, and it is not yet an established fact (or ever will be) that it was due to CVS negligence and not due to the OP's negligence. I don't see why the chargeback would be successful.

Comment: At least where I live you can dispute cc purchases if you do not get delivered the goods you ordered. Op did not get the goods. That puts the burden to sue on the other party if it works. I don't think they answer has any merit tbh.

Comment: @DonQuiKong the OP did get the goods though, and at least in the US the stores print an explicit activation confirmation to prove that. The OP was delivered a gift card with activated value of $500, not $0 as you claim.

Comment: "the OP did get the goods though, and at least in the US the stores print an explicit activation confirmation to prove that." No, they didn't. They bought the gift cards under the belief that they were receiving a secure store of money. They did not receive that. 

"As to tampered packaging - that's a valid claim only until the cash register." Huh? If I buy a package that supposedly contained frozen fish, and I don't realize until I get home that it only contains sand, do I not have a valid chargeback claim.

Comment: "So unless a claim is made and investigated - the issuers have no way of distinguishing those." First party fraud is almost always a possibility. Doesn't mean a chargeback isn't valid. The burden of proof is on the merchant, not the cardholder.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150755/discussion-on-answer-by-littleadv-can-i-dispute-a-credit-card-charge-for-a-hacke); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica I'd appreciate if you removed all the comments, there's a lot of misinformation and misunderstanding in there.

Comment: One wrinkle on the gift card scam that might alter the outcome: I have seen cards that have had the mag stripe erased and some of the number scratched off. I presume that this is to eliminate the possibility the card will be used by the legitimate purchaser after activation, but before the scammer can drain the card. In this case, the card is "defective" at the time of purchase, and I think that alters the analysis.

Comment: I downvoted for the sentence about hiring an attorney.    To talk to a bad/cheap attorney about this in detail would cost 400-600 for the first conversation.    If the attorney had to follow up with Vanilla or CVS it would be well over 2000.   How the h### do you give advice on a money site when your advise could cost more than the scam.    There is no assurance that a lawyer would be any more successful at getting a refund than a person following up.    If anything, once you present a lawyer to CVS they will present theirs and you will lose instantly.

Comment: @blankip when a legal action is mentioned, attorney consultation is  a must. Cost-effect analysis is the OP's responsibility, but in some (most? all?) jurisdictions it's plainly criminal to provide legal advice without being a licensed attorney.

Answer (score 16):

No, you can not dispute the charge.

I'd try going back to that CVS, talking to the manager (who is almost certainly *not* the criminal, they have too much to lose), letting them know they have a tampering/theft problem, and asking them how they are going to deliver the value you paid for.

They may be willing to trade the tampered-with cards for new ones and make a claim against their insurance. You may need to make a police report before their insurance will cover that, and you should do so anyway.

If the store doesn't offer to fix the problem, tell them you're going to get the local newspaper's ombudsman involved; it they still refuse to make you whole, do so. There may be other resources available in your area to put some pressure on them; the police can probably suggest some of them.

If they still don't budge, I agree that the next step is to contact Vanilla, whoever that is.

If you and the recipients are lucky, have a clean record otherwise, and can show that the cards were used far from anyplace you were, you may get one of these layers to take pity on you, *once*. If it happens again, they're going to see a pattern and suspect deliberate fraud.

The real answer, I'm afraid, is that these generic stored-value gift cards are much less protected than a normal credit card, and are should be avoided. If you want to send someone a cash gift as a physical token, write a check.

Comment: If that CVS has a tampering problem, I assure you - they know. The people working there may actually be that very tampering problem. Why would they admit anything?

Comment: They may not admit it. The manager should be told. And, as I said, they may issue replacements. Though you may indeed need to make a police report before their insurance will cover that, and you should do so anyway. If the store doesn't offer to fix the problem, tell them you're going to get the local newspaper's ombudsman involved; it they still refuse to make you whole, do so. There may be other resources available in your area; the police can probably suggest some of them.

Comment: You should add this to your answer.

Comment: What is this "check", of which you speak? I haven't seen one of these (in Europe) in over 20 years...

Comment: @littleadv: *Especially* if the staff are responsible for the tampering, they have a strong incentive to compensate OP on the spot, to avoid the complaint getting escalated to an investigation.

Answer (score 6):

> Can I dispute a credit card charge for a hacked Vanilla Visa Gift Card?

You should try, the squeaky wheel usually gets the grease...

If you've been a long-standing customer with your CC then they may sway things in your favor out of courtesy.

Facts:

1. You bought gifts cards on XYZ date
2. The gift cards were spent after XYZ date

At the end of the day, someone has to eat a loss of $2,000 and I can guarantee you none of the parties involved wish to do that.

As of now, the burden-of-proof rests in your lap to prove **you** did not spend the gift cards yourself and are now trying to make a fraudulent claim/gain.

For proof, go back to that CVS and see if any other cards were tampered with; this assumes they haven't been replaced already. For all you know, the people you complained to are in on the scheme.

Take pictures of the unmonitored location of the gift cards because you may have to write a letter to CVS's corporate headquarters.

Comment: Yep. Exactly this: the burden of proof is on the OP, no-one wants to eat the loss just as the OP doesn't. Not sure why it's such a difficult concept for everyone to understand.

Comment: "As of now, the burden-of-proof rests in your lap to prove you did not spend the gift cards yourself and are now trying to make a fraudulent claim/gain." No, that's not how fraud cases work.

Comment: @Acccumulation the question was about chargeback for the purchase of gift cards. The store will easily prove that the OP has in fact purchased them. The chargeback will fail. I really don't understand what are you all trying to argue here.

Answer (score 2):

If it wears the Visa logo, it has to conform to [Visa's standards for refunding fraud claims (chargebacks)](https://usa.visa.com/pay-with-visa/visa-chip-technology-consumers/zero-liability-policy.html).

Telling you "3 months" is unacceptable at any level.  That is conveniently so far out that 90% of people would forget about it by then, and the 10% who actually follow up could be told "well it's just too late to file a claim now" and other nonsense.  So I can see why Vanilla's Indian call center would say that, but it is violating Visa's rules to say so.

5 days is the standard, so you need to talk to Visa the moment you hear this 90 day nonsense. **You bought the cards on the strength of their brand**.  It's absolutely well within Visa's ability to interdict the revenue stream going to Vanilla or Apple or whomever to assure the chargebacks are paid; ask any small Visa merchant who has had chargeback problems.

Pipelining money into other brands of gift cards is a standard money laundering technique, and Vanilla ought to know that, and if they don't they need to eat the losses until they learn it.

Comment: That's nice. Wrong, but nice. From the link you provided: *Visa's Zero Liability Policy **does not apply to** certain commercial card and **anonymous prepaid card transactions** or transactions not processed by Visa*

Comment: Ah the unfortunate point of OP being an edge case of the question. Federal law limits the consumer liability to $50; however that won't apply to a corporate card.

Comment: @littleadv is correct. A VISA gift card has a different liability policy than a card issued to an individual or corporation. Also, OP didn't say whether these cards were purchased on a corporate or individual account so the $50 consumer liability limit is of unclear relevance.

Comment: @littleadv I don't agree with that interpretation, you've failed to highlight the word "certain" and it should be highlighted IMO.   No evidence that OP's gift card is among the certain ones. Chicago Manual of Style/Oxford comma strikes again!

Comment: Certain refers to "commercial", I'm not sure what is it that you're disagreeing with but feel free to cite the policy itself and not just the title. Even if we assume that you're trying to claim that some anonymous cards are covered - no evidence that the OP's cards are in that group, so I will give you your own argument to deal with.

Comment: @littleadv *Certain refers to "commercial"* wrong, certain applies to both.  If it meant all, it would say "certain commercial card and ALL anonymous prepaid..."  If you're not sure what I'm disagreeing with, then just take my word for it.

Comment: Oh, I take your word that you're disagreeing, I just don't think you're reading it right. But that's OK, I'm used to people not being able to understand simple sentences. It says "certain commercial cards and anonymous cards", if it would mean that not all anonymous cards are included it would have said "certain commercial cards and certain anonymous cards" or "certain commercial and anonymous cards", but that's ok if you disagree, free country. Doesn't make you right, just entertaining

Comment: I'm not arguing, I agree with you that we disagree on the interpretation of that sentence. You can convince me, if you want, by showing the actual policy that would enumerate the exceptions and showing the OP falls into one of them. The fact that instead you're trying to attack me personally shows to me that you have nothing in the policy to substantiate your stance on. That's all. While my tendril of evidence may be slight - you have provided none to support your position other than ad-hominem attack against me.

Comment: Here's the *actual* policy, if you care to read it: https://assets.ctfassets.net/ipocadpk9uyx/4wAj8zhjfZ8JqkyDFkG9wE/d6f58bfb073e0569cee428ff4e9d6876/VV_BOL_Gift_Sutton_CHA.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You engaged in the purchase with the understanding that you were receiving a secure gift card. If this was not the case, if the gift card was compromised, then you didn't get what you thought you were paying for, and you have a valid chargeback case.

You should ask for Vanilla to refund the money, and if they and CVS refuse (or refuse to do so in reasonable time), you should file a chargeback with Citibank and file a complaint with VISA. If Citibank refuses your chargeback, you should file a complaint with MasterCard.

As for people saying you have the burden of proof, that's not how defective product claims generally work. If you claim that you bought a package of fish sticks, and when you got home it was full of sand, the grocery doesn't get to just say "Well, there's no proof that you didn't eat the fish sticks yourself and then fill the box with sand." If you order a package from Amazon and it never arrives, Amazon doesn't get to just say "Well, maybe you *did* get it, and you're just trying to scam us out of a refund."

Comment: *secure gift card* - oxymoron right there. Gift cards are by definition a bearer payment instrument and are not secure in any way shape or form.

Comment: *If you claim that you bought a package of fish sticks, and when you got home it was full of sand, the grocery doesn't get to just say "Well, there's no proof that you didn't eat the fish sticks yourself and then fill the box with sand."* - **Yes**, they do, and they will, and they will be right!

Comment: *If you order a package from Amazon and it never arrives, Amazon doesn't get to just say "Well, maybe you did get it, and you're just trying to scam us out of a refund."* - Absolutely they will. And in fact, they do. Try doing it more than once or twice and not only will they refuse refund, they'll block you as a customer. You do know Amazon deliveries are all photographed, right?

Comment: @littleadv this one seems to have failed as a bearer payment instrument.

Comment: The failure is not on the CVS side, you should dispute the draining transactions with the gift card processor. CVS delivered what they promised, they're not responsible for third party vulnerabilities (they may be responsible for their own, but it's still to be shown that they were in fact negligent).

Comment: @littleadv: You know amazon delivery drivers have been caught on door camera photographing package as delivered and then stealing it right? Also, the scams would not be possible if CVS had kept the gift cards behind the counter.

Comment: @Joshua 99% of them do? You mentioned that as a rule for determining what is the general practice. You say that the scams would not be possible if CVS had kept the gift cards behind the counter, and I can only ask - how, without being the scammer, you could know that? The fact is that I personally have never encountered this scam, and I buy gift cards not from behind the counter all the time, so obviously that's not true.

Comment: @Joshua It doesn't matter where in the store the gift cards are located. They have zero value until the person at the cash register activates them in return for the customer payment. From that point forward, they are a bearer instrument, and can be used by anyone who has possession of them.

Comment: @EllieKesselman: When you figure out how the scam works you will understand.

Comment: @Joshua you keep insisting that there's only one possible way for this scam to work, and I'm not sure why you're so close-minded. As an engineer, I'm sure you can see the myriad vulnerabilities possible throughout the whole supply chain of the physical card or even without ever touching the physical card, to make this scam work. You seem to have encountered only one version of this scam and think that that's the only possible one.

Comment: @littleadv: You are talking about potential ways. I am talking about two actual ways observed in action. Both of these are blocked by the simple move of placing the gift cards behind the counter. However I had figured out how to make the scam work before observing how it worked and had one of the two ways right the first time. I think anybody can figure it out.

Comment: I have observed, working in the industry, at least one way it would work independently of store placement altogether. In fact, that's the only time I've *personally* observed it (as an employee of a firm involved, not personally affected). Swiping it off the shelf and then putting it back hoping no-one would notice the tamper is actually one of the riskier implementations of this scam (for the scammer).

Comment: @littleadv: Then you must surely know your argument about bearer instrument is meaningless.

Comment: @Joshua not sure what you're trying to say. I was arguing that claiming that gift cards are secure is an oxymoron, are you trying to reinforce that argument by saying that one may abuse them without physically bearing them? Yeah, sure, I'll take it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that fraudulent and unauthorized activity happened with the Vanilla and Visa are to be complained to, and it's a crime to be reported to police.  I would see that as a duty whether or not I got my money back.

I had a hacked card in 2003 and Visa has contacted me and asked me about charges in eastern London, while I was in central London. So, Visa can detect and accept geographical information as an indication of fraud.  I was never asked to prove that I had never ridden the ferry to Isle of Dogs, never charged lunch at Burger King, or shopped at World of Leather.

If the fraudulent purchases were in-store, Visa can note the geography and note it doesn't match.  If it was so close-by that subterfuge by the card recipient is suspected, store security video can confirm the purchaser wasn't the card recipient, and parking surveillance may note license plates, make of car and the like.  I'm sure Visa has arrangements with stores that streamline such a request for data.

If the fraudulent purchases were on-line, again Visa should be able to get the shipping address and hopefully a logged IP address, account# and other information (potentially including all sorts of browser cookies), then further find out from the ISP which physical customer would have originated that data stream.  I'm again sure Visa has arrangements with stores that streamline such a request for data.

CVS seems to have given you what you paid for, so I'm not sure CVS or Mastercard would be responsible to make you whole.  The theft of information could have happened before the cards got to CVS, or after you bought them.  CVS may however have a contract with Visa how such goods are stored and displayed, and if they are in violation of that Visa could have a case with CVS.  That said there may be laws in your jurisdiction that help.

I would personally prioritize dealing with Visa, now that Vanilla has given you an untenable timetable.  If that gets no traction, then I would check if I could get help from a local newspaper ombudsman and the Consumer Financial Protection Bureau.  A lawyer would be my next call as that will also be expensive, on top of being a time sink during your business hours.

Comment: The fraudulent purchases were on anonymous gift cards, for which most of the detection mechanisms you're describing would not work. Which is exactly why these types of cards are excluded from the Visa's fraud guarantee mentioned in another answer.

Comment: Granted Visa wouldn't be able to auto-detect them, but would be able to discern them in response to a report, and be able to verify that the cards were used other than by the owner.  The written fraud guarantee doesn't necessarily decide the issue.  They can write it but not honor it for instance by making it too hard to qualify for.  Or they can not write but then give a refund anyway. One assumes Visa wants to continue this business and too many bad stories will mean people will not buy this product--and even perhaps switch to alternate payment mechanisms.